# dnsmasq breaks apt-get

Tags: apt, network-manager, dhcp, aptitude, dnsmasq

I installed dnsmasq and configured it the way I wanted... I hope.
So everything was working great, but now when I try to

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It doesn't really work, it goes very slow and it can't fetch some PPAs.
I am sure that dnsmasq is the problem since if I stop it, update works as usual.

I have Kubuntu 17.04

I use dnsmasq so I don't have to edit the hosts files every time I create a website. so it acts like `*.dev` in hosts files. Here is my config and what I changed.

In `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dev-tld`:

```
address=/dev/127.0.0.1
```

In `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

Comment: I've experienced sort of same problem just now.  don't know how did I create it. But for me, it breaks everything not just `apt`. Killing `dnsmasq` resolved dns!

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out, I needed to refresh my local DNS handling or something of this kind. It can be done with this command `sudo dhclient`.

I saw this here : http://brunodbo.be/blog/2013/04/26/setting-up-wildcard-apache-virtual-host-wildcard-dns